# Unable to load related data - is my configuration wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, relational-database

I have an `ApplicationUser` and a `Group`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? AdminInGroupId { get; set; }
    public int? UserInGroupId { get; set; }
    public Group AdminInGroup { get; set; }
    public Group UserInGroup { get; set; }
    // some more properties
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string GroupAdminId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser GroupAdmin { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> GroupUsers { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `OnModelCreating()` configuration for `Group` (I don't have one for `ApplicationUser`):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasOne(a => a.GroupAdmin)
    .WithOne(g => g.AdminInGroup)
    .HasForeignKey<ApplicationUser>(a => a.AdminInGroupId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Group>()
    .HasMany(u => u.GroupUsers)
    .WithOne(g => g.UserInGroup)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

When running the query below, I'm not getting the `GroupAdmin`:

```
Group group = await db.Groups
    .Include(a => a.GroupAdmin)
    .Include(u => u.GroupUsers)
    .Where(m => m.Id == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

[image]

Notice how `GroupAdmin` is `null`, while `GroupAdminId` has a value.

Answer (score 2):

I Can't understand your database design, why you have one to one and one to many relations in one table. Please check my code may be better for your project.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    // some more properties
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public GroupType GroupType { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
}
public enum GroupType
{ 
 AdminGroup = 0 ,
 UserGroup = 1 ,
 BothGroup = 2
}
```